# Adding WebApi Project to existing ASP.NET Webforms Application

Tags: visual-studio

I have an existing ASP.NET Webforms Application (see image below), and I've added a new WebAPI project. I have a few issues. The first is that according to various tutorials, it should just work, but alas...well, it does work when I right click on the project and Start New Instance in Debug mode. Right now, I have a single project set to start, but it doesn't activate the WebAPI project, and I would like it to. I know that I could set them both as startup projects, but then they end up in different browser windows, which is not what I want.

I would like to know how to get this second project to also start when starting the first, but in the overall solution sense. That way I can start my main site, but also hit the api/Donation url.

[image]

Comment: If you don't want them hosted separately, then you need to put them in the same project. It's simple enough: just look at what configuration ended up in the Web API project and copy it into your existing Web Forms application. It also makes it a great way to learn you way around the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Right click** on your **Solution** and select **Project Dependencies**.

**Tick** Donate for the shop.scramble.org project.

Run the Solution and you'll see in IIS Express both applications are running.

Comment: Ok - I did the first part, but didn't know how to tell about the second part. So it works. Thanks!